# SQL: Query a table twice with different where criteria for each?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

My existing query looks like this:

```
SELECT
       id,
       refid,
       action_id,
       action_type,
       co_user_id,
       cust_vend_id,
       Aes_decrypt(cust_vend_name, '".DBKEY."') AS cust_vend_name,
       Aes_decrypt(amount, '".DBKEY."')         AS amount,
       Aes_decrypt(action_date, '".DBKEY."')    AS action_date,
       Aes_decrypt(memo, '".DBKEY."')           AS memo,
       Aes_decrypt(trans_id, '".DBKEY."')       AS trans_id,
       part_id,
       polarity
FROM   generated_actions
INNER join
        generated_actions.action_id             AS action_id
    ON
        (generated_actions.action
WHERE  acc_type = 2
   AND acc_id = $ba_id
   AND reverse_id IS NULL
ORDER  BY action_id,
          Aes_decrypt(action_date, '".DBKEY."'),
          entry_datetime ;
```

but for each record it selects, I need it to also return another column from a record which would otherwise be excluded (because it's acc_id is '1' not '2'). Therefore I need it to find the acc_id AS 'account' WHERE the action_id is the same as the record it's currently selecting and where part_id = '3'.

The query will select multiple records, but it won't find a match for every record for the additional criteria. In which case it should still return the main record, but with null as the value of 'accounts'.

My alternative, is to go with my supplied query and then for each result, check the same table again SELECT acc_id WHERE action_id = $action_id AND part_id = '3'. I think there must be a way to do this in one query?

I'm using MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
  main.id,
  main.refid,
  main.action_id,
  main.action_type,
  main.co_user_id,
  main.cust_vend_id,
  Aes_decrypt(main.cust_vend_name, '".DBKEY."')   AS cust_vend_name,
  Aes_decrypt(main.amount,         '".DBKEY."')   AS amount,
  Aes_decrypt(main.action_date,    '".DBKEY."')   AS action_date,
  Aes_decrypt(main.memo,           '".DBKEY."')   AS memo,
  Aes_decrypt(main.trans_id,       '".DBKEY."')   AS trans_id,
  main.part_id,
  main.polarity,
  other.acc_id                                    AS other_acc_id
FROM
  generated_actions        AS main
LEFT JOIN
  generated_actions        AS other
    ON  other.action_id = main.action_id
    AND other.part_id   = 3
WHERE
      main.acc_type = 2
  AND main.acc_id   = $ba_id
  AND main.reverse_id IS NULL 
ORDER  BY
  main.action_id,
  Aes_decrypt(main.action_date, '".DBKEY."'),
  main.entry_datetime
;
```

This joins the table to it-self.  It's like having two separate copies of the table.

Because you have two copies, each needs it's own name.  That's what `AS main` and `AS other` does, it just gives each reference to the table a separate name.

The `LEFT JOIN` is like an inner join, except that it always keeps the records from the table on the left hand side - even if it doesn't join to any records in the table on the right.

Comment: Works a charm thanks Dems and I also learned a lot too! Thanks Mitch also, but unfortunately my knowledge level isn't yet high enough to implement your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

This could easily be done as a [procedure](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html) but you could also just execute multiple batches in series.  Consider, if you know the Part_ID's that you need ahead of time, using the [IN clause](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in).

Potentially, get the Part_ID's you need in a subquery that you stuff in the IN Clause.  e.g:

```
SELECT /*actual columns*/ *
FROM table
WHERE predicate_column IN (
    SELECT predicate_column
    FROM table
    WHERE known_column = $known_value
)
```